# How do I select first N letters from words longer than M letters with regexp?

Tags: regex

I need to select first N letters from words longer than M letters with regexp. Is it possible? Let's say N=3, M=5 and the string is:

`We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed`

then my regexp must match

`pre que ans dis`

I can match first 3 letters in all words with

`/\b[A-z]{3}/g`

Now how do I apply this only for words longer that 5 letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
var s = 'We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed'
var r = s.match(/\b[a-z]{3}(?=[a-z]{2,}\b)/gi)
console.log(r) //=> [ 'pre', 'que', 'ans', 'dis' ]
```

**Note:** The character class `[A-z]` includes special characters that fall between in the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need! I forgot to ask if I can repeat the first pattern in a long word? So result must be ['pre', 'fer', 'que', 'sti', 'ons', 'ans', 'wer', 'dis', 'cus', 'sed']

Comment: It would be easy to match words of 5 or more characters then just separate them at every `n` characters.

Comment: exactly! I can match 5+ letter words with `/\b[a-z]{5,}\b/gi`
Now how do I split them every 3 letters?

Answer (score 2):

You can just match two letters which you don't capture:

```
/(\b[A-z]{3})[A-z]{2}/g
```

Are you sure it is `[A-z]` what you want and not `[A-Za-z]` ? `[A-z]` includes the following symbols: `[\]^_'`

Comment: Your expression is wrong. Please go to regexr dot com and check for yourself. Yes, I meant [A-Za-z]

Comment: @Andrey Looks fine to me? What do you mean by "wrong"?

Comment: @melpomene, it matches 5 letters, not 3 as I asked.

Comment: @Andrey Yeah, but it captures only the first 3, so it provides the same information.

Comment: @Andrey you have to take group(1), $1, \1, depending on the language, you are looking at group(0) the entire match. It could be done by `\b[A-Za-z]{3}(?=[A-Za-z]{2})` but this is less performant.